# Where place a jquery code inside a jsp/jstl page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl

Please, someone can tell me where I should place the jquery code below to my page work perfectly? Now, when i click in the first link, the two last rows are hidden, and the other links don't work.

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${usuarios}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"><c:out value="${item.username}"/></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"><c:out value="${item.nome}"/></div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <c:forEach var="tipo" items="${item.tipo}">
                <c:out value="${tipo.nome}"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" id="botaoAuth">Autoriza&ccedil;&otilde;es</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" id="excluirUsuario">Excluir</button>
        </div>
    </div>

            <script>
                $("#botaoAuth").click(function(){
                    $("#<c:out value='${item.id}'/>").toggle();
                });
            </script>

    <div class="row" id="${item.id}">
        <table class="bordered">
            <tr>
                <c:forEach var="item_auth" items="${autorizacoes}">
                        <c:set var="isChecked" value="${false}"/>
                <c:forEach var="user_auth" items="${item.autorizacoes}">
                        <c:if test="${user_auth.nome == item_auth.nome}">  <!-- here compare according ID or any unique attribute -->
                            <c:set var="isChecked" value="${true}"/>
                        </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="${item_auth.nome}" onclick="mudaAutorizacao(${item_auth.nome})"  <c:if test="${isChecked}">checked="checked"</c:if> />${item_auth.nome}
                    </td>
                </c:forEach>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

**UPDATE 001**

I am now with this code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">Login</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Nome</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Tipo</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">#</div>
        </div>

        <c:forEach var="item" items="${usuarios}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"><c:out value="${item.username}"/></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><c:out value="${item.nome}"/></div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <c:forEach var="tipo" items="${item.tipo}">
                        <c:out value="${tipo.nome}"/>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" id="btn_004_${item.id}">Autoriza&ccedil;&otilde;es</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" id="btn_005_${item.id}">Excluir</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" id="row_001_${item.id}">
                <table class="bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <c:forEach var="item_auth" items="${autorizacoes}">
                                <c:set var="isChecked" value="${false}"/>
                        <c:forEach var="user_auth" items="${item.autorizacoes}">
                                <c:if test="${user_auth.nome == item_auth.nome}">  <!-- here compare according ID or any unique attribute -->
                                    <c:set var="isChecked" value="${true}"/>
                                </c:if>
                        </c:forEach>
                            <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="${item_auth.nome}" <c:if test="${isChecked}">checked="checked"</c:if> />${item_auth.nome}
                            </td>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <script>
                $("btn_004_${item.id}").click(function(){
                    alert("clicou para visualizar autorizações do usuario ${item.nome}");
                    $("#row_001_${item.id}").toggle();
                });
            </script>

            <script>
                $("btn_005_${item.id}").click(function(){
                    alert("clicou para excluir o usuário ${item.nome}");
                    $( "#result_2" ).empty().append( "<strong> Pronto! </strong> Usuario ${item.id} excluido." );
                });
            </script>

        </c:forEach>

        <div class="alert alert-success" id="result_2">   </div>
</div>
```

that isn't working at all. but this one below, in the same page, it's working perfectly. Someone can see any error in the code above?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" id="btn_001">Editar atributos dos usu&aacute;rios</button>
<script>
$("#btn_001").click(function(){
    $("#campos").toggle();
});
</script>

    <table class="bordered" id="campos">
        <thead>
        <tr>    
            <th>Campo</th>
            <th>#</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>        
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <c:forEach var="item_campo" items="${campos}">
        <tr id="${item_campo.id}">
            <td> <input type="text" name='<c:out value="${item_campo.id}"/>' value='<c:out value="${item_campo.campo}"/>' size=20 maxlength=40> </td>        
            <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" id="btn_002_${item_campo.id}">Excluir</button> </td>
            <script>
                $("#btn_002_${item_campo.id}").click(function(){
                    $( "#result_1" ).empty().append( "<strong> Pronto! </strong> Campo Excluido." );
                });
            </script>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <tr id="novo">
            <td> <input type="text" name="novo" size=20 maxlength=40> </td>
            <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" id="btn_003">Incluir</button> </td>
            <script>
                $("#btn_003").click(function(){
                    $( "#result_1" ).empty().append( "<strong> Pronto! </strong> Campo Incluido." );
                });
            </script>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="alert alert-success" id="result_1">   </div>
```

**UPDATE 2**
Ok, finally works! after some changes, the final code is:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">Login</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Nome</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">Tipo</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">#</div>
        </div>

        <c:forEach var="item" items="${usuarios}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3"><c:out value="${item.username}"/></div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><c:out value="${item.nome}"/></div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <c:forEach var="tipo" items="${item.tipo}">
                        <c:out value="${tipo.nome}"/>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" id="btn_004_${item.id}">Autoriza&ccedil;&otilde;es</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" id="btn_005_${item.id}">Excluir</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" id="row_001_${item.id}">
                <table class="bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <c:forEach var="item_auth" items="${autorizacoes}">
                                <c:set var="isChecked" value="${false}"/>
                        <c:forEach var="user_auth" items="${item.autorizacoes}">
                                <c:if test="${user_auth.nome == item_auth.nome}">  <!-- here compare according ID or any unique attribute -->
                                    <c:set var="isChecked" value="${true}"/>
                                </c:if>
                        </c:forEach>
                            <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="${item_auth.nome}" <c:if test="${isChecked}">checked="checked"</c:if> />${item_auth.nome}
                            </td>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>                  
        </c:forEach>

        <div class="alert alert-success" id="result_2">   </div>

        <c:forEach var="item" items="${usuarios}">
            <script>
                $("#btn_004_${item.id}").click(function(){
                    alert("clicou para visualizar autorizações do usuario ${item.nome}");
                    $("#row_001_${item.id}").toggle();
                });
            </script>
        </c:forEach>

        <c:forEach var="item" items="${usuarios}">
            <script>
                $("#btn_005_${item.id}").click(function(){
                    alert("clicou para excluir o usuário ${item.nome}");
                    $( "#result_2" ).empty().append( "<strong> Pronto! </strong> Usuario ${item.id} excluido." );
                });
            </script>
        </c:forEach>

</div>
```

Comment: If you're not sure where to add it, wrap it in DOM ready handlers and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I try that, but now none of the links are working, neither a message is display i the browser console for give me any clue what is happening.

Comment: update the question with a more recent code, can you give a look at it?

Comment: Well, it should be `$("#btn_004_${item.id}")`, the ID selector starts with `#` ?